# Ubuntu 15.10 Freezes Frequently

Tags: drivers, 15.10, freeze

I am running 15.10 on a Toshiba Satellite L15W-B1208D Laptop and it freezes frequently. Before marking this as a duplicate please read all of the things I have tried. I have tried every solution I've found on the forums so far.

Before I get into the solutions I've tried I'll better define what I mean by "freeze". They screen locks up and nothing is responsive at all. The mouse doesn't move, the backlit keys such as caps lock do not light up when pressed, I cannot ssh into the machine, it no longer appears on my WiFi network, and REISUB does not have an effect on the machine. It's as if the computer is off, but the screen is stuck on a certain image.

Thinking that I possibly had an issue with my hard drive, I ran badblocks and found that the hard drive was in good shape. Thinking that it might just be an issue with Ubuntu I decided to dual boot with Arch for a while, but it still froze with Arch Linux. I tried just wiping my hard drive with dd from a live disk and reinstalling, but it still freezes. I tried booting from a live USB for a while, but it still froze on the live USB.

Thinking that I had a potential problem with my RAM I ran memtest86 on my computer for about 24 hours and no errors were found. Thinking that it could be my graphics card I downloaded a program designed to overclock the graphics card, ran it for ~18 hours, and it didn't freeze.

Thinking maybe some components were overheating I installed software to monitor the temperatures of the CPU cores, graphics card, etc. When it froze with that software running all temperatures were in the healthy ranges.

Some additional info: It seems to freeze far more often on Chrome (especially while using Netflix) than it does when using firefox. It usually freezes while a web browser is open, but has also frozen just while running commands from the terminal, when the terminal is the only program running. Ubuntu is currently the only OS installed. The issue existed when I was using 14.10 on the same machine, but has gotten worse with 15.04 and 15.10. Is it likely some kind of issue with my drivers? That's all I can think of, a driver issue.

Here is the output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Comment: I wish I had a better answer for you, but have you tried Ubuntu 16.04? 16.04 reflects nearly 6 months of kernel and driver updates and bugfixes over 15.10, and might be worth a try if 15.10 is giving you problems.

Comment: Just finished updating to 16.04. I'm attempting to stream a movie to see how it works out. I'll update my post if this fixes the problem.

Comment: No such luck, 16.04 freezes as well. I'm almost certain it's the graphics driver as I've realized that using an HDMI to connect to a tv makes it freezes much more frequently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it by creating a file called `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` containing the following:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver     "intel"
   Option     "NoAccel"   "True"
   Option     "DRI"       "False"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not the display driver making the freeze. Its the CPU energy saving "C state". You add kernel parameter to prevent CPU entering above C state 1.

edit `/etc/default/grub` and edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line adding `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` to whatever might already be there. After saving the file run `sudo update-grub`, then re-boot.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar Toshiba system. I have the L15W-B1220, and I have the same hard freeze issue as you, and I have installed all the different flavors of Ubuntu from 14.04lts, 14.10, 15.04, 15.10, and 16.04, including all the sub flavors, Mate, Gnome, Kubuntu, etc, all of them lock up.

My belief is it's a kernel issue mostly. Installing the package toshset is supposed to allow us to control the Toshiba ACPI system from the command line, but the software reports that the kernel isn't configured to use Toshiba, which is incorrect, as kernel modules toshiba-wmi, and toshiba_acpi load/initialize just fine.

I believe the real issue is the cooling system in these Toshiba 2 in 1 devices in Linux. It doesn't seem to be able to detect any fan in the device, even though it works fine in Windows 10.

Your solution did not work for me, just broke the xserver. I have the same i915 chipset.

But I think I found a decent work around. I installed a few packages to monitor my CPU temps. ( apt install tlp tlp-stat thermald, lm-sensors, psensor, etc )  This low power consumption quad-core CPU supports throttling, so I set up thermal trip points to manage the temperature in the chassis... Disabling Turbo mode in the bios was the first step so it doesn't ever burst the clock speed to 2.6ghz, and keeps the CPU at its normal rated speed of 2.1ghz. When the temperature hits 55 Deg C, I have it set to drop the clock speed to its lowest (500mhz), and also drop the SATA chip down to power save (same thing happens when you unplug the a/c power source).

Other things I configured were to shut off the charging when it gets to 98%, when the AC is plugged in, so it runs completely on the battery until about 80% before starting the charge process again.... If you leave the AC plugged in when the battery is at 99-100% charge, the heat increases dramatically. The system does not freeze in Windows 10 at all, everything seems to work as expected, so the issue is with the Toshiba "Bios" not reporting to Linux the exact acpi addresses needed for the internal hardware. Linux likes to match your system to a T, which is great for performance. Windows on the other hand, Toshiba, only seems to care about developing its windows drivers...

Its not an optimal solution (work around), but it is a work around that seems to be holding up well so far the past week. Hopefully a solution comes out of the bug report I sent in for Ubuntu 16.04.